# Create an custom appender in log4j which stores the log in memory

Tags: log4j

I want to create  an custom appender using log4j in java programatically which stores the log in memory(Certain size will be defined for e.g.  say DEFAULT_SIZE=20) & as soon as memory is full(there are 20 logs in memory) create an json array of those logs and send it to the server. Along with log message i also want information such as (class, file name,line number,method name,level etc.)

Help is appreciated.!!!

Updated ::

Below is the source code developed by me for the same . Problem which i am facing is i get line number, method name,file name as "?".I dont understand what is the reason.

```
package com.any.logger;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class Log4jAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {


private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 20;
private ArrayList<LoggingEvent> buffer;
private int bufferSize;

public Log4jAppender() {
  this.bufferSize = Log4jAppender.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
  this.buffer = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();
}


public void close() {

}

public boolean requiresLayout() {

  return false;
}

 @Override
 protected void append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {


synchronized (buffer) {
  if (buffer.size() >= bufferSize) {
   try {
      System.out.println("Hello");
      Log4jService service = new Log4jService(new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>  
            (buffer));          
       System.out.println("Buff >");
       service.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to write logs");
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    buffer.clear();
  }
  }
}

  buffer.add(loggingEvent);
}

}



package com.any.logger;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class Log4jService implements Runnable {

private ArrayList<LoggingEvent> buffer;
private Thread t;
private boolean flag;

public Log4jService(ArrayList<LoggingEvent> buffer) {
    this.buffer = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>(buffer);
    this.flag = false;
}

public void start() {
   if (!flag) {

     this.flag = true;
     this.t = new Thread(this);
     this.t.start();
}
}

 public void run() {
    if (flag) {
     String json = getLogJson(buffer);
    }
 }

   /**
    * Method to get the json log
    * 
    * @param logEvents
    *            arrayList of log events
    * @return an String which is json file
    * @throws JSONException
   */

   private String getLogJson(ArrayList<LoggingEvent> logEvents) {

   System.out.println("In getLogJson");

   JSONObject logger = new JSONObject();

   try {

         JSONArray logs = new JSONArray();

         String message = "";
         String time = "";
String level = "";
String tag = "";
String file = "";
String exceptionName = "";
String exceptionReason = "";
String line = "";
String clas = "";
String method = "";

int index = 0;

SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");         
for (Iterator i = logEvents.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
LoggingEvent logEvent = (LoggingEvent) i.next();

boolean chk=logEvent.locationInformationExists();

System.out.println("Check :: "+chk);

clas=logEvent.getClass().toString();
JSONObject log = new JSONObject();


message = logEvent.getMessage().toString();
time = String.valueOf(formatter.format(logEvent.getTimeStamp()));
level = logEvent.getLevel().toString();


    if (chk) {
    System.out.println("hello");
    file = logEvent.getLocationInformation().getFileName();
    line = logEvent.getLocationInformation().getLineNumber();
    method = logEvent.getLocationInformation().getMethodName();
}

if (logEvent.getLevel() == Level.ERROR || logEvent.getLevel() ==  
            Level.FATAL) {  
    exceptionReason = message;
}

log.put("message", message);

log.put("time", time);
log.put("level", level);
log.put("tag", tag);
log.put("file", file);
log.put("exceptionName", exceptionName);
log.put("exceptionReason", exceptionReason);
log.put("line", line);
log.put("class", clas);
log.put("method", method);

logs.put(index, log);

index++;
}

JSONObject logsObj = new JSONObject();
logsObj.put("logs", logs);

logger.put("log", logsObj);

System.out.println("Logs Array :: " + logsObj);
System.out.println("Logger Object :: " + logger);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

return logger.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the source code for log4j2 and use an existing appender as a template for my custom appender. SocketAppender and TCPSocketManager may be good places to start.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/net/TCPSocketManager.html

Currently the buffering is based on the number of bytes, not event count. If you follow the existing appender/manager pattern then in your custom appender manager you will need to have a large enough buffer and flush every 20 events. (Perhaps also flush after some timeout? You may only get 19 events and nothing after that...)
You could also do the buffering in the appender, keep a list of event objects there and only call pass them to the manager to be written after some threshold is reached.

The default Layout for SocketAppender will use java serialization. You'll need to roll your own JasonLayout. The log event object has all the details you mentioned.

Comment: Hii Remko Popma , first of all thanx for the suggestions & secondly i have edited question with my source code.If u can have an glimpse at it & can help me around it would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ankit, I see you're using log4j-1.2... I'm more familiar with 2.0. One thing:  appenders  can be configured to not take LocationInfo (AsyncAppender has a config option for this). What about your custom appender? Is it (or its parent class) taking the location info when the log event object is created?

Comment: Ya i am using log4j-1.2.17 ... That is what i am trapped in. I have log4j.properties file where i specify log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.LocationInfo=true , but it is not giving me the correct output.I dont know where i am paddling it wrong.

Comment: Would you mind posting your question on the log4j user mailing list? That way you'll be asking the experts directly.